# RMarkdown PDF section and subsection color

Tags: r, colors, r-markdown, sections

I used a different color on sections and subsections in my rmarkdown document, but in the reader the names in sections (bookmarks) pane are now blank.

```
\textcolor{mycolor}{My section}
```

It looks like even if I revert `mycolor` to black (`{RGB}{0,0,0}`), the issue persists, so I assume I'm incorrectly using the `\textcolor{mycolor}{Section text to color}`.

Is there another way? Also, is there a way to apply the same color to all sections/subsections?

[image]

Comment: So you used `# \textcolor{mycolor}{My section}` and `## \textcolor{mycolor}{My subsection}`?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I used ## and ###, but the same result with first level #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an arguably better approach to accomplish your goal of colored section headings:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{sectsty}
  - \sectionfont{\color{red}}
  - \subsectionfont{\color{green}}
  - \subsubsectionfont{\color{blue}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Section

This section header should be red.

## Subsection

This subsection header should be green.

### Subsubsection

This subsubsection header should be blue.
````

[image]