# How to add coloring to PDF reports in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

How to add background colors to specific section of the text while creating PDF reports using rmarkdown. Something like below

[image: click here for image]

i tried something like this but it is working in latex but not in rmarkdown

```
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\rlap{\color{DarkGreen!90}\rule[-0.5ex]{\linewidth}{3ex}\vspace{-3ex}}\sffamily\Large\color{white}}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

[this is how it looks in latex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EWRp.png)

[this is in rmarkdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1O56.png)

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
- \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{titlesec}
- \usepackage{sectsty}
- \usepackage{xcolor, soul}  
- \sectionfont{\color{red}}
- \subsectionfont{\color{green}}
- \subsubsectionfont{\color{blue}}
- \titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\rlap{\color{DarkGreen!90}\rule[-0.5ex]{\linewidth}{3ex}\vspace{-3ex}}\sffamily\Large\color{white}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

---
\section{Highlights}
# Section
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323425/13249862

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows is which documentclass etc you are using?

Comment: Can you post the markdown code in a code block instead of an image?

Comment: Probably markdown will automatically load the xcolor package with different options and thus causing the error message

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  i'm not sure about that even i tried individually making section to highlight in background it didn't work.

Comment: Post the code and we will see

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  can you please check i have edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

- rmarkdown already loads xcolor without paying attention to the options you need. As a workaround you could trick markdown by passing the necessary options to all packages
- `sectsty` will destroy all changes you do via `titlesec`. Don't load them both

---

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
classoption: svgnames
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
- \usepackage{titlesec}
- \usepackage{soul}  
- \titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\rlap{\color{DarkGreen!90}\rule[-1.5ex]{\linewidth}{3ex}\vspace{-3.5ex}}\sffamily\Large\color{white}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

---
\section{Highlights}
# Section
```

[image]